# db2: select on two criteria in same column

Tags: db2

Hi I think I am overlooking a problem I have using sql db2. I have two columns - person and car. I want to find people that have purchased both a mclaren and a ferrari.

I have done:

```
select distinct person,car from car_db
where car = 'ferrari' and car = 'mclaren'
```

however this is returning no people, even though eyeballing the data, there are people which have bought both. there must be a way to pick out those people who have purchased both. any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways.

One simple way would be to select the set of people who have purchased one car, and use an inner join to match them up against the set of people who have purchased the other car.

```
WITH F AS
(SELECT DISTINCT PERSON 
   FROM CAR_PURCHASES
   WHERE CAR = 'FERRARI'
), M AS
(SELECT DISTINCT PERSON 
   FROM CAR_PURCHASES
   WHERE CAR ='MCLAREN'
)
SELECT F.PERSON
  FROM F JOIN M  ON f.person = m.person
```

Another might be to use grouping

```
WITH Q AS
(SELECT PERSON,
       MAX( CASE WHEN CAR='FERRARI' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BOUGHT_FERRARI,
       MAX( CASE WHEN CAR='MCLAREN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BOUGHT_MCLAREN
   FROM CAR_PURCHASES
   GROUP BY PERSON
)
SELECT PERSON 
  FROM Q
  WHERE BOUGHT_FERRARI > 0   
    AND BOUGHT_MCLAREN > 0   
  ORDER BY PERSON
```

There are plenty of other ways, but now you have some idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

This question is tailor-made for the `INTERSECT` operator, and is far simpler to read / understand than solutions that use `JOIN`.

It's basic set theory:

```
select person from car_db where car = 'FERRARI'
INTERSECT
select person from car_db where car = 'MCLAREN'
```

`INTERSECT` will automatically remove any duplicates.  If you wanted the duplicate `person` records, you could use `INTERSECT ALL`.

Note, you can use the `EXCEPT` operator to find people who own Ferraris but do not own McLarens:

```
select person from car_db where car = 'FERRARI'
EXCEPT
select person from car_db where car = 'MCLAREN'
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the good old inner join? You need the distinct in case someone bought 2 Ferrari or 2 McLaren.

```
select distinct F.PERSON 
from CAR_PURCHASES F inner join CAR_PURCHASES M on F.PERSON = M.PERSON 
where F.CAR = 'FERRARI'
  and M.CAR = 'MCLAREN'
```